# Make worksheets visible only to certain users

Tags: excel, vba

I need your advise as I cannot figure out how to make it work. I have a worksheet that start with a log-in form to ask user identification. Now based on this user name, I'd like to allow only certain worksheets to be visible and the rest hidden. However ever I cannot enter anymore username, or username work but all sheets are visible - how could I make it work properly?

as I couldn't make it work for a certain user, I tried to see in the below code if I could limit the sheets to all users, but even this didn't work. Before banging my head to the wall, turning to your advise, many thanks in advance for your help :)))

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Login_Initialize()
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
If Me.IntranetID.Value = "Admin" Or Me.IntranetID.Value = "user1" Or Me.IntranetID.Value = "user2" Or Me.IntranetID.Value = "user3" then
LoginFlag = True

Worksheets("excel1").Visible = True
Worksheets("excel2").Visible = True
Worksheets("excel3").Visible = True
Worksheets("excel4").Visible = True

Dim strIntranetID As String
Dim strText As String
Dim wksDestination As Worksheet

strSheetName = IntranetID.Value
Set wksDestination = Worksheets("Excel1")
strText = IntranetID.Text
wksDestination.Activate
wksDestination.Range("B46").Value = strText

Worksheets("Excel2").Activate "this is to make the user to start from the main sheet"

Unload Me
Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "You are not authorised to use this Workbook"
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```

I'd like the above code to still allow 1) log-in form 2) allow user to see only certain sheets i.e. User 1 can see Excel 2 and Excel 3 etc..
3) I'd like the user to start in Excel 2 as it is the main sheet.

Comment: [This might help](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+unhide+sheet+vba&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&rlz=1I7ADRA_en&gws_rd=ssl#gws_rd=ssl&kpvalbx=1&spf=1548174846211)

Comment: FYI this is security theater and shouldn't be used to prevent users from viewing sensitive data.

Comment: I understand the "theater aspect", truth is I cannot generate a password note to each users thus the idea to limit its access by the user name - the list is not mentioned, so anyone lambda that would want to open it, will not be allowed to do so. I will read the Indentation to see how it can help it out - thanks for sharing Mathieu

Comment: Thanks for the spot @MathieuGuindon - actually, I have 10 allowed users in the original code, but I removed them for obvious confidentiality and forget the  <       Then >  that was at the end - I re-added it to the above code for clarity. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must always be at least one sheet visible - so create a blank sheet to show for unauthorised users. You need to run a routine at close of workbook to hide all but that sheet. Then On_open show the logon form and ask for ID. Based on that response show the appropriate sheets and hide the default sheet

```
 Sub WorkBook_Open()
 UserForm("login").Show
 End Sub

 Sub WorkBook_BeforeClose()
 Dim ws as worksheet
 For each ws in worksheets
     select case ws.index 
          case is =  1  'assume default sheet is index 1
              ws.visible = xlsheetvisible
          case else
              ws.visible = xlsheetveryhidden
      end select
   next ws
  end sub
```

In the form you can use a similar process to hide and unhide sheets - just remember that there must always be one sheet visible, so don't try and hide anything before making a sheet visible.

You also need to password protect the VBA editor if you want to ensure that users don't simply unhide sheets from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot - however, how would you restrict the visible sheets to only certain users. As ex. as the admin, I want to access all sheets, however user 2 should access only to sheet 2 and sheet 3 only based on the login form. In the above code, I'm confused on how to determine which user can access to which worksheets :)

Comment: In your login form you ask their name and then selectively unhide the appropriate sheets using worksheets("sheetname goes here").visible - xlsheetvisible

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was able to make the change you proposed above and decide based of the User Name, which worksheets could open. The message box is appearing for my access, but it succeed on unhiding all the sheets - so it is working - thank you very much for your help :)